# How to prevent tmpfs /tmp causing machine to run out of memory?

Tags: debian, fstab, tmp, tmpfs

I have a virtual server (Debian 8.5, OpenVZ) that seems to run out of memory* when tmpfs-based `/tmp` is about 60% full.

(* while the system reports 2GB of memory still free, processes start to behave erratically, `/tmp` writes fail with `ENOSPC`, forking fails with `ENOMEM`, some connections drop with `ENOBUFS`, and eventually `sshd` starts closing connections during handshake).

Is this normal for `tmpfs`, or is my system somehow horribly misconfigured?

Can it be fixed by shrinking size of `/tmp`?

How can I resize `/tmp` if it's not in `/etc/fstab`?

---

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop25777p1  150G   19G  126G  13% /
devtmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs              2.0G   17M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              2.0G   68K  2.0G   1% /tmp
none               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
```

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620    0    0
none  /run/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0    0
```

Comment: This looks like your VPS provider has oversubscribed the node. Go somewhere else, and avoid OpenVZ.

Answer (score 1):

`tmpfs` is a filesystem in memory, that can hog your memory if you have a lot of tmp files that do not get cleaned up.

You can use the filesystem for `/tmp` by editing `/etc/default/tmpfs` and reboot.

But you should really find out why `/tmp` is filling up.

Edit: You can also limit the size in the file...

Comment: My program is deliberately filling up tmp as long as there's more than 10% free space on /tmp. The problem is that machine dies long before tmp is full.

Comment: Then you should either limit the size, or move to disk.